# Google Cloud Datastore very slow after trying to get more than 100 000 entities

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

I'm trying to get the large amount of entities with runQuery request.

I have an entity kind Task, which contains:

- integer id
- integer TaskGroupId
- non-indexed string field (~200B)

The request body:

```
{
 "query": {
  "kind": [
   {
    "name": "Task"
   }
  ],
  "filter": {
   "propertyFilter": {
    "property": {
     "name": "TaskGroupId"
    },
    "value": {
     "integerValue": "501"
    },
    "op": "EQUAL"
   }
  }
 },
 "partitionId": {
  "namespaceId": "local"
 }
}
```

I have ~2 000 000 entities of this type. If I try to run the request which should return about 100 000 entities it will take ~4 minutes to execute.

Is it appropriate performance or am I doing something wrong?

Is there any way to speed up this request?

Comment: How are you determining the amount of time taken? What does the timing code look like? At ~208 bytes per entity, for 100,000 entities, it might be rational that it takes this long. You might want to do whatever you're doing via MapReduce or using [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) as opposed to loading them all into one place.

Comment: I determine the amount of time taken by `console.time()` before the request and `console.timeEnd()` after.

Comment: I found the temporary solution for my problem:  

1. Before the request I have the ids of all tasks.  
2. Split the ids list into chunks  
3. Run get by key request via map/reduce inside my node js application.  
4. I receive the result in ~40 seconds.  

According to the above solution, it doesn't look like the entity size issue. It seems that non-primary key queries in datastore are really slow.